# Android TableLayout cell colspan

Tags: android, html-table, cell, tablelayout

For my bachelor thesis I want to implement an android application. For testing purposes, I created a tablelayout. The rows and containing cells are depending on the user input. For getting some experiences with the tablelayout, I created a tablelayout with 7 cells programmatically: In the first row are header cells, each with colspan=2.

Now, I'm removing step by step a cell in the second row (from right to left).
Everything is fine. I removed a cell in the second row once again. See the image: [table with 5 cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u97nc.png). Everything is fine. But now, when I recompile or make an instant reload, this occurs: [table with 5cells, but wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMiTa.png). Whats happening here? I changed nothing in the code... Something magic happened?! I tested this workaround in an android virtual device(api 17). Api 17 is required. With a virtual device with api 25, the error not occurs.

Can someone help me?

Here's a part of the code:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
params.span = 2;
params.weight = 1;

TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);

TableRow row1 = new TableRow(context);
TableRow row2 = new TableRow(context);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
tv1.setText("header");
tv1.setWidth(300);
tv1.setHeight(100);
tv1.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv1.setBackground(darkBackground);
tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
row1.addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(context);
tv2.setText("header");
tv2.setWidth(300);
tv2.setHeight(100);
tv2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv2.setBackground(darkBackground);
tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
row1.addView(tv2);
```

Comment: It's generally recommended to create your layouts using the AS layout builder / XML, not manually creating them in code. With the layout builder you can also see how your layout will look without running it / on different device screens.

Comment: For my application purposes, the internal layout builder is not applicable. Users can define a table in an external xml file, which will be imported. The table structures can differ from user to user.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I found the solution. It's all about the background. The background (grey) in the second picture (table with 5cells, but wrong) (first row, first cell) does not fit the complete width, because of an incorrect definition of the GradiantDrawable-Object. I forgot to set the shape attribute:

```
GradiantDrawable background = new GradiantDrawable();
background.setColor(Color.rgb(235,235,235));
background.setStroke(1, Color.rgb(0,0,0));
// don't forget to set the following attribute:
background.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
```